# nginx lction not found 404

Tags: php, nginx

Поссле добавления блока location /admin/system/tests/ajax {...} роут перестал быть доступным, вылетает ошибка 404

Не силен в nginx, помогите разобраться в чем дело.

Если важно для чего я это пытлся сделать, то:
Требовалось увеличить timeout выполения скрипта php для указанного маршрута. request_terminate_timeout и max_execution_time настроены

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    client_max_body_size 48M;

    root /var/www/html/название/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name название;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

            # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
            # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /admin/system/tests/ajax {
        fastcgi_read_timeout 500;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 500;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю ранее этот url обрабатывался у вас в `location /` и далее происходил rewrite на `location ~ \.php$`. Теперь же так не происходит т.к. вы создали новый location.

Полагаю что там у вас есть какой-то php скрипт и нужно передать ему запрос.

Тогда добавьте в этот location тоже, что у вас в `location ~ \.php$`.

Возможно понадобится прописать еще директивы:
[fastcgi_param](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_param).
Минимально необходимые параметры:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/www/scripts/php$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING    $query_string;
```